# html2canvas conflict in mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas` libary. The code takes a `div` and save its content as `png`. It works fine with `opera` and `chrome` but while i run the code in `firefox` it does not save the div as png. No action happens on clicking the download button in firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="html-content-holder">
      Div part to save as png
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" type="button" value="Download" />
    <script>
      $('#btn-Convert-Html2Image').click(function() {
        html2canvas($('#html-content-holder'), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
            a.download = 'somefilename.png';
            a.click();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define _does not work_

Comment: When i am pressing the download button it does not save the div as png. No action happens when i click the button

Comment: Any error in console ? Can you share a fiddle to work with ?

Comment: Why do you have two `html2canvas` libraries loaded? It may be the issue cause.

Comment: @Justinas : I tried it incase html2canvas isnt working from the link. Though i moved it later. That didnt help. Still the same problem

Comment: @RayonDabre: https://jsfiddle.net/onik_18/24vvg6zm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Keep an `hidden` anchor element in the `DOM` and update the `href` property of the element inside `onrendered` handler.

```js
$('#btn-Convert-Html2Image').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#html-content-holder'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = $('#download').get(0);
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
      a.download = 'somefilename.png';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="html-content-holder">
  Div part to save as png
</div>
<input id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" type="button" value="Download" />
<a href="" id='download'></a>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/24vvg6zm/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for the Firefox as well as other browsers too.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Rayon

Answer (score 3):

You need to append the anchor element to the body in Firefox.

```
html2canvas($('#html-content-holder'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        a.download = 'somefilename.png';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Better to  keep an element in the DOM and update `href` property otherwise it will create _needless_ `<a>` elements..