# Using Chart.js, how do I avoid having tooltips overlap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using [Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) via [Angular Char](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). I have displayed all the tooltips in order to download a chart with the information displayed by creating a [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/tk31rehf/).

The tooltips overlap, there doesn't seem to be any logic to distribute them so that they don't. Is there a way to do this?

Some of the plugin code. This isn't important to my question. The 'beforeRender' function creates a new Chart.Tooltip for each item in the dataset and afterDraw renders them:

```
// turn on tooltips
chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
tooltip.initialize();
tooltip.update();
// we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
tooltip.pivot();
tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
```

The chart:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No - seemed impossible, or at least too complicated for a job. Put the tooltips on hover and the values into the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve some overlap solution using these snippets:

```
tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    yPadding: 2,
    xPadding: 2,
    caretSize: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
}
```